# Object Storage on SoftLayer - how to support multiple environments

Tags: development-environment, production-environment, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

What is the typical pattern to support multiple environments (Development, Test, Production etc) when we use ObjectStorage on Soft Layer?

Is using a separate SoftLayer account for each environment a overkill?

Does it make sense to use one SoftLayer account for Dev/Test environments and another one for Production environments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the company.  Most larger companies will use separate accounts; one development and testing, then one for production.  In terms of Object Storage, it is possible to have more than one Object Storage account within the same SoftLayer account.  If you are simply using Object Storage, then, you will not need separate SoftLayer accounts to have separate Object Storage accounts.